# Ethernet shield: sending data from web to arduino using html form

Tags: html, web, arduino, ethernet

I have already completed the controlling of devices through internet using buttons. I used Arduino Uno+ SD CARD+ Ethernet shield. Now I want to modify it so that used can send text commands through form submission to control the same.

I could do it when I was using the Arduino Uno Memory for HTML code but now facing problems when I am using SD Card for HTML. Expecting the code module for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But you'll need to use a web socket. I've done that using PHP.
So, you'll create a page with html and php that, when you click on the submit button, will send the commands. It must be like that, in php:

```
<?php 
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

socket_connect($sock,"ip number of arduino", 8080);

$messsage = '0';
if (isset($_POST['on'])){
    $msg='1';
}
if (isset($_POST['off'])){
    $msg='0';
}

socket_write($sock, $msg);
?>
```

So you just need to write a html to send the post method when a form be submited.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without php? Its just, that i cant use php on my ethernet shield.. Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: But you won't use php on the ethernet shield. You'll need a server on the web. So you'll hostage the php on the server, then you'll just need to access it.
On the arduino you'll have a web client. Just like the samples of the ARDUINO IDE.

Comment: I found everything I needed here (http://engenheirando.com/projetos/automacao/). 
It's in portuguese, try using google translator.

Comment: Hey, why would u need $message variable?

Comment: Sorry,  it's not $message.  It should be $msg

Answer (score 2):

Submission of HTML form actually invokes POST or GET method of HTTP protocol. This protocol is human readable.

Example of HTTP request from w3schools :

```
POST /test/demo_form.asp HTTP/1.1
Host: w3schools.com
name1=value1&name2=value2
```

This is what you'll get into arduino buffer. You can simply search for name1= pattern and read the value and act accordingly.

In the example below I read values of variables s and e.

```
word len = ether.packetReceive();
word pos = ether.packetLoop(len);
if (pos) {
  bfill = ether.tcpOffset();
  char* socket = strstr((char *)Ethernet::buffer + pos, "?s=");


  if(socket != 0){
    byte s = getIntArg(socket, "s");
    byte e = getIntArg(socket, "e");
    Serial.println("Request");
    Serial.println(s);
    Serial.println(e);
    PlanActions(s, e)
    }
```

Form for this request looks like:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <select name="s" size="1">
        <option value="0">TV</option>
        <option value="1">HiFi</option>
    </select>
    <input name="e" type="submit" value="0">
    <input name="e" type="submit" value="1">
</form>
```

In the example I'm sending simple form page from arduino, but you can have the page wherever you want. It can be on local computer or web server. Just change action to something like `<form action="arduino-ip"`

Comment: Just would like to emphasize, here you are using the arduino as the server (which might seem a bit backwards, but just don't think about a server as a large powerful machine) Also, you really want to do like Jakub said and serve up the page that creates the get from another server, if you are serving up a lot of text from the arduino you will soon run out of memory (in which case it is just hanging)